# Java DynamoDB Validation exception required "key not given" when exists in JSON

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Running into exception while running dynamoDB `.putItem()`.

Table definition:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "storage_CACHE_KEY",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "my-table",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "storage_CACHE_KEY",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "CreationDateTime": "2017-11-01T05:01:18.883Z",
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 3,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 3
  },
  "TableSizeBytes": 199,
  "ItemCount": 1,
  "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/my-table"
}
```

Additionally value I'm attempting to put when serialized into JSON appears like so:

```
{
  "storage_CACHE_KEY" : "storage_cache_key_value",
  "some_other_fields" : [""]
}
```

I still can't figure out why the below errors are occurring:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: One of the required keys was not given a value (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:
```

Update: How .putItem is being used

```
public <T> PutItemResult put(String key, T value, Optional<Long> expires) throws JsonProcessingException {
    PutItemRequest req = (new PutItemRequest()).withTableName(this.tableName).withItem(this.keyValuePair(key, value, expires));
    return this.db.putItem(req);
}
private Map<String, AttributeValue> buildKey(String value) {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap();
    key.put("name", new AttributeValue(value));
    return key;
}

private <T> Map<String, AttributeValue> keyValuePair(String key, T value, Optional<Long> expires) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> item = this.buildKey(key);
    item.put("json", new AttributeValue(this.mapper.writeValueAsString(value)));
    if (expires.isPresent()) {
        item.put(this.ttlKey, (new AttributeValue()).withN(((Long)expires.get()).toString()));
    }

    return item;
}
```

I have stepped over this code and have seen that `T value` is JSON in precisely the format I have posted above.

Update: putItem succeeded when I changed the map entry from `name` to `storage_CACHE_KEY` but now read fails to marshal back to my object. The json stored in my local dynamodb for the entry is:

```
{
  "storage_CACHE_KEY": "4728264794434232301",
  "json": "{\"storage_CACHE_KEY\":\"23232432472826479401\", \"otherFields\": \"example\"}"
}
```

(0 known properties: ])
Unrecognized field "present" (class java.util.Optional), not marked as ignorable

Comment: please post your code how you invoke putItem method. seems something is wrong with putItem method arguments.

the following code works fine for me :
`amazonDynamoDB.putItem("my-table", new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>(){{
            put("storage_CACHE_KEY", new AttributeValue().withS("storage_cache_key_value"));
            put("some_other_fields", new AttributeValue().withSS(Arrays.asList("hello", "bye")));
        }});`

Comment: Show your putItem code. You say it's in the "JSON" but if you are using Java you don't create JSON directly when using DynamoDB.

Comment: why the key is set as "json"? It should be "storage_CACHE_KEY" as defined in table (i.e. hash key attribute name).

Comment: @notionquest json is the raw data. When I changed the above "name" entry to "storage_CACHE_KEY" the put worked but now the read fails to marshal back to my class type: Unrecognized field "present" (class java.util.Optional), not marked as ignorable

Comment: I updated question above with details

Comment: Please show how are you reading? Are you using DynamoDBMapper class ?

Answer (score 3):

I just spent a whole day resolving an instance of this error. I haven't researched your question to see if it is relevant but offer it for what its worth. My cause was creating the table one way and accessing it another. Specifically I was creating the table with `createTable` in `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document` (which returns a Table) when I should have been using `createTable` in `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2` (which returns a CreateTableResult). If you create with the former and then try and access the table from the Java mapper with `mapper.load()` you get the error.

Just to complete the confusion if you describe the table to a `TableDescription` and then convert that to a String with `.toString()` you get exactly the same description (net of creation date and such) whichever way you created the table. But for all that they aren't the same to the Java mapper.

Comment: in my case it was clash between service originated tables that are getting created at runtime and manually created ones. thus deleting all and rerunning whole migration from scratch worked, thanks for sharing this piece of experience